# Create hover on map area?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I made some map area on my img and I want to create on this area new layout on hover with some text.(http://take.ms/RUwsh). What can you reccomend me to do?

```
<img src="http://s12.postimg.org/3v7tu6d1p/flat.png" alt="" class="img-responsive centered" usemap="#Map3" />
<map name="Map3" id="Map3">
<area alt="" title="" href="javascript:void(0)" shape="poly" coords="26,61,56,53,91,48,133,41,170,37,212,35,241,33,294,36,322,37,357,39,392,46,425,51,455,59,457,61,457,307,455,321,450,341,442,363,430,383,412,403,390,423,373,433,342,449,324,456,304,461,283,466,267,468,246,468,217,467,189,463,164,457,138,449,108,434,87,419,68,401,51,381,37,355,28,331,25,315" />
</map>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v7309Ldn/1/

Comment: Create a div wrapper/container and use pesudo elements before or after

Comment: Are you looking to do [something like this](https://jsfiddle.net/v7309Ldn/5/)?

Comment: @hungerstar yes, thank you